# Zuul: automatic rerouting incoming requests to other service instance in case of unavailable service

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have configured Zuul with Eureka in a way, that 3 identical instances of a service are working parallely. I am calling the gateway on the port 8400, which routes incoming requests to ports 8420, 8430 and 8440 in a round-robin manner. It works smoothly. Now, if I switching off one of the 3 services, a small amount of incoming requests will go wrong with the following exception:

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Filter threw Exception
    => 1: java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    => 3: hu.perit.spvitamin.core.batchprocessing.BatchProcessor.process(BatchProcessor.java:106)
    caused by: com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Filter threw Exception
    => 1: com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:227)
    caused by: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.util.ZuulRuntimeException: com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    => 1: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:124)
    caused by: com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    => 1: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:198)
    caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: com.netflix.client.ClientException
    => 1: com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:118)
    caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: scalable-service-2:8430 failed to respond
    => 1: rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:57)
    caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: scalable-service-2:8430 failed to respond
    => 1: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
```

My Zuul routing looks like this:

```
### Zuul routes
zuul.routes.scalable-service.path=/scalable/**
#Authorization header will be forwarded to scalable-service
zuul.routes.scalable-service.sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
zuul.routes.scalable-service.serviceId=template-scalable-service
```

It takes a while until Eureka discovers the service is not available any more.

My question is: Is there a possibility, to configure Zuul so that in case of a NoHttpResponseException, it forwards the requests to another available instance in the pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to the problem. The appropriate search phrase was 'fault tolerance'. The key is the autoretry config in the following application.properties file. The value of template-scalable-service.ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer must be set at least to 6 in case of 3 pooled services to achieve full fault tolerance. With that setup I can kill 2 of 3 services any time, no incoming request will go wrong. Finally I have set it to 10, there is no unnecessary increase of timeout, hystrix will break the line.

```
### Eureka config
eureka.instance.hostname=${hostname:localhost}
eureka.instance.instanceId=${eureka.instance.hostname}:${spring.application.name}:${server.port}
eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled=false
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=true
eureka.instance.secure-port=${server.port}
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=5
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds=10

eureka.datacenter=perit.hu
eureka.environment=${EUREKA_ENVIRONMENT_PROFILE:dev}
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_SERVER:https://${server.fqdn}:${server.port}/eureka}
eureka.client.server.waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty=0
eureka.client.registry-fetch-interval-seconds=5
eureka.dashboard.path=/gui

eureka.server.enable-self-preservation=false
eureka.server.expected-client-renewal-interval-seconds=10
eureka.server.eviction-interval-timer-in-ms=2000

### Ribbon
ribbon.IsSecure=true
ribbon.NFLoadBalancerPingInterval=5
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=30000
ribbon.ReadTimeout=120000

### Zuul config
zuul.host.connectTimeoutMillis=30000
zuul.host.socketTimeoutMillis=120000
zuul.host.maxTotalConnections=2000
zuul.host.maxPerRouteConnections=200
zuul.retryable=true

### Zuul routes
#template-scalable-service
zuul.routes.scalable-service.path=/scalable/**
#Authorization header will be forwarded to scalable-service
zuul.routes.scalable-service.sensitiveHeaders=Cookie,Set-Cookie
zuul.routes.scalable-service.serviceId=template-scalable-service
# Autoretry config for template-scalable-service
template-scalable-service.ribbon.MaxAutoRetries=0
template-scalable-service.ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer=10
template-scalable-service.ribbon.OkToRetryOnAllOperations=true

#template-auth-service
zuul.routes.auth-service.path=/auth/**
#Authorization header will be forwarded to scalable-service
zuul.routes.auth-service.sensitiveHeaders=Cookie,Set-Cookie
zuul.routes.auth-service.serviceId=template-auth-service
# Autoretry config for template-auth-service
template-auth-service.ribbon.MaxAutoRetries=0
template-auth-service.ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer=0
template-auth-service.ribbon.OkToRetryOnAllOperations=false

### Hystrix
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false
```

Beside of this, I have a profile specific setup in application-discovery.properties

```
#Microservice environment
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled=true
```

I start my server in a docker container like this:

```
services:
    discovery:
        container_name: discovery
        image: template-eureka
        environment:
            #agentlib for remote debugging
            - JAVA_OPTS=-DEUREKA_SERVER=https://discovery:8400/eureka -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
            - TEMPLATE_EUREKA_OPTS=-Dspring.profiles.active=default,dev,discovery
            - EUREKA_ENVIRONMENT_PROFILE=dev
        ports:
            - '8400:8400'
            - '5500:5005'

        networks: 
            - back-tier-net
            - monitoring
        hostname: 'discovery'
```

See the complete solution in [GitHub.](https://github.com/nagypet/wstemplate)

Answer (score 1):

`Eureka`, by default, requires *lease* to be renewed every `90s`. That is, if a service instance doesn't get its lease renewed in `90s`, `Eureka` server will evict the instance. In your case, the `instance` has not been evicted yet - the renew window for the instance was valid.

For this, you can decrease the `renew` duration through config setup at `eureka client` and `eureka server` as described [here.](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3652#issuecomment-604524285)

**Note:** If you hit the `actuator /shutdown` endpoint, the instance is immediately [evicted](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3652#issuecomment-532459112)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, I could improve my setup. Now its better, the ungracefully killed service client disappears in 10 seconds, but within this 10 seconds Eureka keeps forwarding requests to the killed client. I'm looking for a solution in which Eureka would try to forward the requests between service unavailability and eviction to other services of the same kind as long there are more than 1 instances registered with the same application name.

Comment: @PeterNagy *but within this 10 seconds Eureka keeps forwarding requests to the killed client.* Well, this thing is handled at Eureka code. So, there is not much you can do is this situation. Either narrow (`~2s`) the renew time and have a retry mechanism at Zuul or hit the `actuator /shutdown` endpoint for shutdown. This will send explicit call to Eureka to evict the instance